# jQuery show hide multiple links slide toggle div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about toggle effects. I have managed to be able to toggle the same div which is my goal, my problem is I want to add in the effect that say if (toggle1) is on and I click on toggle2, it will close toggle one and open toggle 2. Right now, if you click on any toggle it just opens and closes the toggle based on the state it is in. I want to be able to switch whatever is in the div when clicking on a different toggle. I hope this makes sense. http://jsfiddle.net/nbh2w/

HTML

```
<div>
<a href="#" id="toggle3">Slide Toggle3</a><br /><br />
<a href="#" id="toggle4">Slide Toggle4</a><br /><br />
<div class="toggle" style="display:none; background-color:#4CF;width:100px;height:200px;"></div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
    $(function() {
    $('#toggle4').click(function () {
    $('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');

    return false;
        });
});

    $(function () {
    $('#toggle3').click(function () {
    $('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');

    return false;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve but based on my understanding, this might be what you want.
     
        Slide Toggle3
        Slide Toggle4

```
 </div>


    $(function() {
    $('#toggle4').click(function () {
        $('.toggle').hide('1000');
        $('.toggle').text('toggle 4 clicked');
    $('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');

    return false;
        });
});

    $(function () {
    $('#toggle3').click(function () {
        $('.toggle').hide('1000');
         $('.toggle').text('toggle 3 clicked');
    $('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');

    return false;
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rNqd5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use an instance of `this`, also, you're going to need two div's for each link:

```
<a href="#" id="toggle3">Slide Toggle3</a>
<div class="toggle" style="display:none; background-color:#4CF;width:100px;height:200px;"></div>

<br><br>

<a href="#" id="toggle4">Slide Toggle3</a>
<div class="toggle" style="display:none; background-color:#4CF;width:100px;height:200px;"></div>
```

You should also use a class for your links, but I just comma separated the ID's

```
$("#toggle3, #toggle4").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nbh2w/2/

Comment: that just opens and closes each link. I need it to open and close the same div. Picture a navigation that is opening and closing 1 Div. That is what I'm shooting for.

Comment: It is opening and closing based on the state its in. So say i click toggle 1 to open and then toggle 2, it closes the first toggle but doesn't open up what I want for toggle 2.

Comment: @Keith -- Use `$(".toggle").slideUp();` and then `slideDown()` right after.

Answer (score 0):

You need some thing like this ?

```
  $('#toggle4').click(function () {
               $('.toggle').hide();
                $('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');
                 return false;
                });
```

[**Try it**](http://jsfiddle.net/nbh2w/4/)

Comment: Yes except when you click on the first toggle and it opens, I want to be able to close that toggle when I click the second as it opens up the new information.